# ¿Cómo recuperar registros de varias tablas sin UNION?

Tags: sql, mysqli, join

compañeros!

Trabajo en una base de datos MySQL, versión del cliente: libmysql - 5.6.43

**CONTEXTO.** Tengo una base de datos que contiene dos tablas, las cuales tienen justo la misma estructura, los mismos campos, todo igual, sólo cambia el nombre de la tabla. A modo de ejemplo el contenido de estas dos tablas es como sigue (en realidad hay cientos de registros):

*Tabla 1*

id: 1 - nombre: Ariadna - email: ariadna@ariadna.com

id: 2 - nombre: Atenea - email: atenea@atenea.com

*Tabla 2*

id: 1 - nombre: Thomas Hobbes - email: thomas@hobbes.com

**OBJETIVO.** Realizar consulta que recupere todos los registros de todas las tablas.

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO.** Sé que existe la opción *UNION*, para lograr lo que necesito. El problema es que no puedo utilizar UNION (no me sirve) porque la paginación se hace imposible. Por eso utilizo CROSS JOIN.  Aclaración: no hay ninguna relación entre los registros de ambas tablas, por eso no pongo el *ON*. Mi consulta es la siguiente.

```
SELECT t1.id AS t1_id, t1.email AS t1_email, t1.nombre AS t1_nombre, t2.id AS t2_id, t2.email AS t2_email, t2.nombre AS t2_nombre
FROM tabla1 AS t1
CROSS JOIN tabla2 AS t2
WHERE 1
```

Esta consulta me devuelve lo siguiente (pasado a un array PHP):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [t1_id] => 1
        [t1_email] => ariadna@ariadna.com
        [t1_nombre] => Ariadna
        [t2_id] => 1
        [t2_email] => thomas@hobbes.com
        [t2_nombre] => Thomas Hobbes
    ),
    [1] => Array (
        [t1_id] => 2
        [t1_email] => atenea@atenea.com
        [t1_nombre] => Atenea
        [t2_id] => 1
        [t2_email] => thomas@hobbes.com
        [t2_nombre] => Thomas Hobbes
    )
)
```

Es cierto que la consulta me devuelve todos los registros de ambas tablas, es decir, los 3 registros totales. Pero ¡qué forma de devolverlos! No quiero que el único registro de la tabla 2 se repita en cada uno de los registros recuperados de la tabla 1.

**PREGUNTA.** ¿Cómo lograr que la consulta me devuelva esto?

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [t1_id] => 1
        [t1_email] => ariadna@ariadna.com
        [t1_nombre] => Ariadna
    ),
    [1] => Array (
        [t1_id] => 2
        [t1_email] => atenea@atenea.com
        [t1_nombre] => Atenea
    ),
    [2] => Array (
        [t2_id] => 1
        [t2_email] => thomas@hobbes.com
        [t2_nombre] => Thomas Hobbes
    )
)
```

**...**

**...**

**...**

**EDICIÓN 1**

Pongo el código PHP mediante el cual hago la consulta a la BBDD:

```
$query = "
    SELECT t1.id AS t1_id, t1.email AS t1_email, t1.nombre AS t1_nombre, t2.id AS t2_id, t2.email AS t2_email, t2.nombre AS t2_nombre
    FROM tabla1 AS t1
    CROSS JOIN tabla2 AS t2
    WHERE 1";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    if($stmt->rowCount()>0) {
        while ($fila = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($fila);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega por favor tu código php que usas para obtener los valores

Comment: Precisamente UNION es para resolver tu problema. Pon como estas haciendo la consulta. Quizás el problema es que tienes que englobar los campos dentro de otra delect superior y ahí controlar el paginsdo, pues tienes exactamente los mismos campos no? El único problema será ordenarlos por id porque seguramente estarán repetidos, pero si los ordenas por nombre o email saldrán bien.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder. Acabo de editar la pregunta para añadir el PHP mediante el cual hago la consulta a la BBDD.

Comment: Sobre los registros de ambas tablas, @Jakala, tienes razón, los IDs sin duda se repiten. Pero también existe la posibilidad de que se repitan los demás campos, porque las personas que aparecen en una tabla, pueden aparecer en la otra!

Comment: Igual que he hecho pruebas pudieras prescindir del bucle y directamente hacer un fetchAll asignándole ese valor a una variable y ya no debería salir duplicado

Comment: Ahora entiendo tu problema. Es de suponer que si hay un email repetido, los otros campos serán repetidos también (pero en si el registro sera igual)? Creo que entonces hay que jugar con el unión y el DISTINCT del select.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mí mismo.

Este tema de los valores repetidos provenientes de la BBDD era el menor de mis problemas, ya que siempre puedo jugar con PHP para recuperar de la respuesta lo que necesito y se acabó. El problema esencial (y que no especifiqué originalmente en mi pregunta, cosa que creo debí hacer) es que no podía formar una query SQL que me permitiera recuperar datos como los necesitaba y además que esa misma query me funcionara para la paginación. El **UNION** (en vez del **CROSS JOIN**) me recuperaba los datos tal como yo los necesitaba pero no vi la forma de trabajar la paginación con una query con UNION (creo que fue el cansancio del momento el que me volvió ciego).

**Jakala** sugirió que precisamente *UNION* era lo que debería resolver mi problema (+1), así que después de leer su comentario me di a la tarea de pensar (nuevamente) cómo lograr que UNION funcionara con la paginación, y resultó que encontré la forma de hacerlo. Esto me confirma una vez más que dentro de los foros hay mucha gente valiosa que aunque no te dé la respuesta explícita a tu problema (como por ejemplo: haz esto y luego esto otro, y luego multiplica por esto, etc), sí te sugiere un camino, abriéndote horizontes que no habías visto, o que si ya habías visto (como en mi caso), te conminan a regresar a caminos olvidados porque ahí está la respuesta aunque no la hayamos visto antes.

Después de pensarle un poquito cómo lograr que *UNION* funcione con un sistema de paginación, me di a la tarea de trabajar y terminé con esto. Pongo el código resumido, para a quien le sirva:

```
$query_from_pagination = $form_query; // $query_from_pagination guarda el valor del atributo 'data-query' del paginador (ver más abajo)
$form_page             = (isset($form_page)) ? $form_page : NULL;
$offset                = ($form_page-1) * 10;
$registrosXpagina      = 10;
$query_base            = '';

// --> Armamos la query a ejecutar <--
// Si la petición viene del paginador
if ($forma==='mipaginador') {
    // Para armar la query según la página solicitada del paginador, simplemente reemplazo las marcas que puse (XXX y YYY) en la query guardada en cada ítem del paginador, por sus valores reales, que son el número de página solicitada y el número de registros a recuperar. ¡Así de fácil!
    $query = str_replace('XXX', $offset, $query_from_pagination);
    $query = str_replace('YYY', $registrosXpagina, $query);
}
// Si la petición viene del solo hecho de cargar la página
else {
    foreach ($arrayMisTablas as $id => $tabla_data) {
        $query_base .= "(SELECT id,nombre,email FROM tabla_".$id." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT XXX,YYY) UNION ";
    }
    $query_base = rtrim($query_base, ' UNION ');
    $query = $query_base;
}

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // ...
}

// --> Armado del paginador <--
if ($num_pages1>1) {
    $paginador .= '<div class="row">';
    $paginador .= '  <div class="col-lg-12">';
    $paginador .= '    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">';
    $paginador .= '      <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">';
    for ($i=1;$i<=$num_pages1;$i++) {
        $class_active = '';
        if ($i == 1) $class_active = 'active';
        $paginador .= '    <li class="page-item '.$class_active.'">';
        $paginador .= '      <a class="page-link" href="#" data="'.$i.'" data-paginador="mipaginador" data-query="'.$query_base.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        $paginador .= '    </li>';
    }
    $paginador .= '      </ul>';
    $paginador .= '    </nav>';
    $paginador .= '  </div>';
    $paginador .= '</div>';
}
```